# How to validate scss

Tags: css, ruby, validation, sass

I have a scss file, and I compile it into a css file using scss. The scss to css compiler detects the errors in the scss file, but it seems too tolerant. That is, even when I mistype the name of the style attributes, it compiles without an error. Is there a way to make it return an error when there is a style attribute in the scss file that does not exist in css3 or in the imported features? There is also a possibility of writing an invalid value for the styles, but I know that is more complicated, and I am not asking for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [Ruby wrapper](https://github.com/alexdunae/w3c_validators) around the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) so you can write a simple script to check the output css from scss.

I also found [this](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass-validator) integration with [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) so if you use [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) to compile your scss, it might be helpful. I haven't used this so I'm not sure how it works but I've had a good experience with the [W3C CSS Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd really like the same thing built into rails or my development environment somehow.

I found this online tool to be incredibly helpful (it finds errors, but also hints at things I was doing that could cause unintended results)

http://beautifytools.com/scss-compiler.php

Copy paste `.scss` file into the left hand side and click 'Compile SCSS'

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, if you want a validator that's built into your NodeJS development (there may be others for different languages too, but this is what I found),
scss-validator: https://www.npmjs.com/package/scss-validator

Comment: The question tends to be tied to `gem` package manager instead of `npm` so a ruby solution might be more suitable.